# Post showing img HTML instead of graphic

Tags: html, wordpress

Why do all new WordPress posts with a graphic or link show the corresponding HTML code instead of the image or link?

When I create a new post I use the visual editor, and I press Add Media, then select a graphic that I have uploaded, and the graphic shows as expected in the visual editor. I then press Preview and the full “img” HTML text shows in the preview window instead of the graphic. When inspecting the Preview window’s img element, it has quotes around the whole img element, thus treating it as text. The same issue happens when inserting a link – the full “a” HTML text is displayed.

This happens for me on the the default install of WP 4.7.3. Installed WP 4.7.3 to a fully patched Windows 7 64-bit PC. Apache 2.4.23, PHP 7.1.3, MySQL 5.7.15 with utf8mb4_general_ci collation (also tried utf8_default_collation). No plugins are active (I only have the 2 default plugins installed). No themes other than 3 default, and Twenty Seventeen is active. Using Chrome 57/Safari/Firefox all do the same thing.

I’ve installed on another Windows PC and get the same issue. If I press Add Media and add the graphic, then switch to the text editor, it shows the “img” element text correctly in the editor. When I preview this text view or publish it, it shows the full “img” element as text just like publishing from the visual editor view. If I manually enter an “a” link element, it shows the full “a” HTML not just the link’s visible text. All these scenarios show the HTML instead. 
 Restarted Apache, cleared cache, checked all Apache and PHP logs and no errors show in Chrome console.

Comment: Are you using the WYSIWYG editor? Have you attempted to switch to "Code" view to see and remove the `" quotes "`?

Comment: Aren't there any Wordpress forums anywhere to ask such broad questions?

Comment: I asked in the WordPress support forum but have received no answers yet.  Users on SO always respond sooner.

Comment: Going from the visual editor with the graphic visible, to the "code" or text view, it does not have quotes around the img code - It looks as it should.  Quotes only get added after previewing it or publishing it.

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem was caused by the filter setting in the php.ini file.  From a previous PHP application the following setting was set:

filter.default = full_special_chars

This wrapped the post information in quotes.  Commenting out this setting solved the problem.